# Receive and Make calls: Egypt to UK without extra fees

Tags: uk, egypt, communication, roaming

I have an Egyptian mobile number and UK mobile number and live in the UK, I would like to be able to:

1. Receive calls made to my Egyptian number without charging the
   caller extra fees.
2. Make calls from my Egyptian mobile number to other numbers in
   Egypt

Roaming seems to be expensive so I am looking for something reasonably cheaper to solve any of the 2 problems, is this possible and what sort of options do I have?

Answer (score 5):

This is possible.  My partner does this, she has one British SIM in her phone where she makes/takes British calls, and one Czech SIM where she makes/takes Czech calls. This way she avoids any fee's from foreign numbers, but I believe it depends on the specific provider you use, as some of them may charge extra for making calls outside of Egypt.

Alternatively have you considered using calls over something like WhatsApp or Skype, this way you can make the same type of voice calls, to anywhere in the world, using either WiFi or a data plan instead of charging as a phone call?

Comment: Not sure why this answer has so many up-votes. The solution is not applicable to the situation in question, since this only works because there are no roaming fees when using a Czech subscription in the UK. That will BTW soon change, when (if) the UK leaves the European Union. It is also not possible to use Skype or WhatsApp to receive calls in the UK made to the Egyptian cell phone number.